# Listview error, add range c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I can't make my function work to copy my listview from the previous form.

Form1 Code:

```
private void customerInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Customers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {

            var myformmessagedialog = new MessageBoxForm
            {
                name = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text,
                address = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text,
                telephone = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text,
            };
            myformmessagedialog.LoadListView(Customers.Items);
            myformmessagedialog.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
```

Form2 (Messageboxform) code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClaudsPizzeria
{
public partial class MessageBoxForm : Form
{
    public MessageBoxForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string telephone;

    public void LoadListView(System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection          items)
    {
        orderListView.Clear();
        orderListView.AddRange(items);
    }

    private void MessageBoxForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblName.Text = name;
        lbladdress.Text = address;
        lbltelephone.Text = telephone;
    }
}
}
```

ERROR I GET:

```
Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition for '      AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Claudiu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ClaudsPizzeria\ClaudsPizzeria\MessageBoxForm.cs  27  27  ClaudsPizzeria
```

All I want to do is copy my listview from my main form to my messagebox form and I get that. I'm new to c# so I'm sorry if I ask stupid questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you meant:

```
orderListView.Items.Clear();
foreach(ListViewItem x in items) {
    orderListView.Items.Add(x);
}
```

You access the items of a `ListView` through the `Items` property. You may also want to wrap it in `orderListView.BeginUpdate()` and `orderListView.EndUpdate()` to reduce flickering.

Edit: If you're displaying them in another `ListView`, you need to clone them. So:

```
orderListView.Items.Clear();
foreach(ListViewItem x in items) {
    orderListView.Items.Add((ListViewItem) x.Clone);
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I do foreach.. Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' C:\Users\Claudiu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ClaudsPizzeria\ClaudsPizzeria\MessageBoxForm.cs 29 41 ClaudsPizzeria

Comment: It works, just it gives me another error. "Cannot add or insert the item 'c' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it.
Parameter name: item". Is it because I have the listview displayed in my first form?

Comment: @ClaudiuBadau: Yes, you can't add a `ListViewItem` to more than one `ListView` at a time. You can clone them instead, using [`ListViewItem.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.clone.aspx).

Comment: How would I clone them from one form to another as in my example?

Comment: @AdamRackis: Well... neither did I :) The error message was actually useful for once. Thanks, though!

Comment: @ClaudiuBadau: Create a new `List<ListViewItem>` and, for each item in the `items` collection, add `item.Clone()` to your list. Then you can use that instead.

Comment: Use CopyTo of the collection and copy it to an array like `ListViewItem[]`

Comment: @V4Vendetta: That won't clone the items themselves.

Comment: @minitech.. I've tried to clone and still am not getting the code right.. can youu help? so far I have this.   ListViewItem clone = new ListViewItem(); public void LoadListView(System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection items)
        {
            
            foreach (ListViewItem x in items)
            {
                clone.SubItems.Add((ListViewItem)x.Clone());
            }
        }

Comment: Thank you minitech for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these new items to the `Items` collection of your ListView.  You can't add them directly to the ListView itself.

```
orderListView.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Ditto with clearing the existing items:

```
orderListView.Items.Clear();
```